# Access link which is behind Active Directory Federation Services using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, ntlm

I have a website which use Active Directory Federation Services to authenticate the user. I want to access a URL for the site using HttpWebRequest class in code. But when I try that, I get a 401 error. After some research I found that it uses NTLM authentication. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520703/sending-http-headers-with-http-web-request-for-ntlm-authentication). But I see that the response I get is a HTML page with some hidden fields and it has a javascript to submit the page on load. The action URL will be that of my domain. I tried  to submit the HTML text as a form manually but again I get the same response. Not so sure how I can access the page. Anyone has an Idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with just such an issue over the past few days. After trying many things I eventually resorted to the following method:

1. Create a System.Net.CookieContainer object and pass it to the CookieContainer of every httpwebrequest.
2. Manually parse the form elements and pass them off as the RequestStream to the form's target. This must be done as POST and not GET on the httpwebrequest.
3. For any consecutive request, make sure you attach the same CookieContainer. There is where your authenticated ADFS cookies are stored. Without them you'll just hit an endless loop.

Regards