# How to add Win Auth header to HttpClient's request c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I need to simulate `Win Auth` http header for `HttpClient`. It could be something like the following , see the `Authorization` header :

```
POST http://url HTTP/1.1
Host: http://127.0.0.1/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: /
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/
Content-Length: 18
Origin: http://127.0.0.1/
Connection: keep-alive
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAADAAAAGAAYAIQAAABuAW4BnAAAAAAAAABYAAAAFgAWAFgAAAA
WABYAbgAAAAAAAAAKAgAABYKIogoAACgAAAAPUOVvBWOMBKcZqtqFzf+fmWQAZwByAHUAZAB6AGkAbgBzA...
```

Please, give me some examples how to encode domain username & password for that http header, i found only examples for `BASIC` authentication. But there are `windows authentication` & `NTLM`.

Comment: https://developer.gnome.org/evolution-exchange/stable/ximian-connector-ntlm.html or http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html seem to give some info

Comment: @steve Yes, thanks, but there is only specification, i need to get some trusted c# code snippet to encode domain username & password to base64 string from appropriate format.

Comment: You mention HttpClient, but if you can use HttpWebRequest you might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520703/sending-http-headers-with-http-web-request-for-ntlm-authentication

Answer (score 0):

Put the domain credentials in the [HttpClientHandler.Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx) property and the [AuthorizationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.authenticationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) will do the Auth dance for you and fill in the Authorization header as required.