# Use NTLM Authentication in Web Request in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, ntlm

**Update**
Turns out all I needed to do was upgrade to .NET Core 2.1! Thanks for the solutions everyone!

---

I have a .NET Core 2.0 Console App and need to make a web request to an API which uses Windows Authentication (NTLM specifically). It's an internal API in my company and I'm having a hard time trying to connect to it successfully, keep getting 401s.

**My research**

I checked out on SO:

- [NTLM authentication HttpClient in Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822842/ntlm-authentication-httpclient-in-core) - raised last year, no proper answer given saying that the issue would be resolved in a later .NET Core update.
- [Sending HTTP Headers with HTTP Web Request for NTLM Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520703/sending-http-headers-with-http-web-request-for-ntlm-authentication) - this was in 2009 and doesn't appear to be relevant for .NET Core.
- [How to get HttpClient to pass credentials along with the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212116/how-to-get-httpclient-to-pass-credentials-along-with-the-request/12675503#12675503) - this was in 2012, thought it'd be the one but still get 401 when using it.

I then found this issue which was raised in the .NET Core github and it says [it has been resolved](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25988). I tried following [a code example there](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25988#issuecomment-401129910) but still did not work.

**My code**

Here is what I have so far, I changed the Uri as it's hosted on the company network, but I hope this will be sufficient to run locally.

```
public class NTLMProxy
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public NTLMProxy()
    {
        _httpClient = CreateHttpClientWithNTLM();
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetUsers()
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, _httpClient.BaseAddress);

        return _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest);
    }

    public HttpClient CreateHttpClientWithNTLM()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://ntlmservice.com/services/api/foo");
        var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache { { uri, "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials } };
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialsCache };
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = uri };
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 120 * 1000;  // Close connection after two minutes

        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

If you have any ideas / suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Why not use .NET Core 2.1 instead of 2.0? Even your linked example states that it works in .NET 2.1.

Comment: I realised that just after I posted the question (woops), updating Visual Studio now and will try it out using .Net Core 2.1 and will update on progress.

Comment: Is NTLM and windows authenthenthication the same thing? This is what works for me for windows authenthication HttpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler {UseDefaultCredentials = true}). I don't have the CredentialsCache thing, not sure if the code is doing the same thing in the background.

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev people use both to mean Windows Authentication

Comment: @Trozza the long-term support version is 2.1, not 2.0. 2.0 is already unsupported. You should move to 2.1 anyway

Answer (score 6):

For .NET Core 2.1 I have this implementation working, using a `HttpClientFactory`

In `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` in the `class Startup` I have this named `HttpClient` registration:

```
        services.AddHttpClient("myName").ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(_ => new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Credentials = new CredentialCache { 
                {
                    new Uri("url"), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")
                }
            }
        });
```

At the location where you need the `HttpClient` just resolve it like this:

```
var client  = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("myName");
```

Don't forget to inject the factory in the constructor.

```
public class MyClass{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public MyClass(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }
}
```

Good luck!