# c# code to fetch http response code of a intranet application as a specific user

Tags: c#

I'm trying to test if a intranet web application is up using C#. And i tried it using the below code, but it gave me a 401 error though i have access to the app. And in the Angelfish logs i do not see user name for the get request.
How can i improve the below code to create the get request as myself.

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
// Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Status Code is OK and StatusDescription is: {0}",
                          myHttpWebResponse.StatusDescription);
// Releases the resources of the response.
myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```

Comment: why do you think that you have access? are you sending proper headers (auth/user-agent/etc)?

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520722/9365244

Comment: when i hit the same url using browser i'm able to access the app, in the request i'm just sending the url and nothing else

Comment: @JayV, thanks for the link - is there a way to fetch just the status code

Comment: @Py_learner The `HttoResponse` object has a property call `StatusCode`. This is the documentation for it: [HttpWebResponse.StatusCode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thank you @JayV it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working code -

```
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
req.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
req.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Status Code is OK and StatusDescription is: {0}", myHttpWebResponse.StatusDescription);
}
// Releases the resources of the response.
myHttpWebResponse.Close();
```